# Inserting a transparent png using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

How to insert a circular PNG on an other image without getting a white border around the circle using Tkinter?

[image]

```
image_path = "D:/Programming/Python/projs/weeknd.png"
image = Image.open(image_path)

background_path = "D:/Programming/Python/Music_Player/Android Small - 1.png"
background_image = Image.open(background_path)

# resize the image

image = image.resize((165, 165), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# create a Tkinter-compatible image

tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
tk_background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)

# create a label to display the image

background_image_label = tk.Label(root, image = tk_background)
background_image_label.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_image)
label.place(x=105,y=150)
```

Comment: The ONLY way you can get the transparency of one image to interact with another image is if they are both part of the same Canvas.  Labels, like all Tkinter widgets, are opaque rectangles - the only thing you can possibly see through the transparent areas of an image on a Label is the Label's background color.

Comment: Also it's best to avoid overlapping widgets.